# DISTINCT Django Query

Tags: django, django-models

I want to use `distinct()` in Django but want to return the QuerySet not ValueSet.

Since I want to distinct on a particular column and get all the other columns as well, I cannot use a ValueSet.

Currently I'm using:-

```
daily_count = ShipmentSubSortScanMapping.objects.all().values('shipment_id').distinct()
```

This return only `shipment_id`, but I want all the fields.

Here's my model:-

```
class ShipmentSubSortScanMapping(models.Model):
    received_arm_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    actual_arm_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = 'None')
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment',related_name ='subsortscans')
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True)
```

Comment: why do you specify `values()` if you need also the other fields? `distinct()` works also without `values()`

Comment: But I want distinct on 'shipment_id' not on other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) accepts an argument of what fields to operate on, so probably you want:

```
daily_count = ShipmentSubSortScanMapping.objects.all().distinct('shipment_id')
```